# request.getRequestURL() get http instead of https

Tags: tomcat, servlets, haproxy

I would know why request.getRequestURL() in my servlet returns http instead of https even I call it with https?

In the back I have tomcat as a web server and haproxy as a reverse proxy and load balancer
If someone can tell me why and how I can configure tomcat or haproxy to doesn't change the request, I looked for proxyPreserveHost but there is no equivalent for haproxy
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a reverse proxy (HTTP), then Tomcat needs to know that the protocol used by the proxy is secure. To do that, you have to set a few things in your `<Connector>` in `conf/server.xml`:

```
<Connector
    secure="true"
    scheme="http"
```

You may also want to set the following, though they may be unnecessary in your environment:

```
    proxyName="www.example.com"
    proxyPort="443"
```

See the [Tomcat Configuration Guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes) for more information.